# What did Ayn Rand mean by " men’s rejection of reason in favor of faith, and of self-interest in favor of self-sacrifice."?

Tags: libertarianism, history, totalitarianism

Basically, this statement is included in one of her book in subject of reasons, how totalitarianism developed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This quote is actually misattributed to Rand - in fact, it was written by Leonard Peikoff in 2008 in the introduction to a new edition of *We the Living*. He wrote:

> The basic cause of totalitarianism is two ideas: men’s rejection of
> reason in favor of faith, and of self-interest in favor of
> self-sacrifice. If this is a society’s philosophical consensus, it
> will not be long before an all-powerful Leader rises up to direct the
> faith and sacrifice that everyone has been extolling. His subjects
> cannot resist his takeover, neither by exercising their faculty of
> thought nor their passion for values, because these are the two
> priceless possessions they have given up. The end result is thought
> control, starvation, and mass slaughter.

Reason and self-interest are central to the Objectivist philosophy. Objectivism advocates rational egoism - an action can only be 'rational' if the consequences of the action are in line with ones own self-interest. The quote above is perhaps better explained by Peikoff in his book entitled *Objectivism: The Philosophy of Ayn Rand*:

> The concept of "egoism" identifies merely one aspect of an ethical
> code.  It tells us not what acts a man should take, but who should
> profit from them. Egoism states that each man's primary moral
> obligation is to achieve his own welfare, well-being, or self-interest
> (these terms are synonyms here). It states that each man should be
> "concerned with his own interests"; he should be "selfish" in the
> sense of being the beneficiary of his own moral actions. Taken by
> itself, this principle offers no practical guidance. It does not
> specify values or virtues; it does not define "interests" or
> "selfinterest"—neither in terms of "life," "power, " "pleasure," nor
> of anything else. It simply states: whatever man's proper
> self-interest consists of, that is what each individual should seek to
> achieve.
>
> The alternative is the view that man's primary moral
> obligation is to serve some entity other than himself, such as God or
> society, at the price of subordinating or denying his own welfare. In
> this view, the essence of morality is unselfishness, which involves
> some form of self-sacrifice.

The first quote, then, expands on this - if enough people act in a self-sacrificial manner, without regard for their own self-interest; combined with a proclivity to act with faith rather than reason, it is inevitable - according to Peikoff - that a figurehead will arise to take advantage of this; a totalitarian leader. The populace, in its new capacity, will be unable to resist.

Comment: Comments deleted. This is not an appropriate platform to debate philosophy.